# How do I use an external variable inside an eloquent each method?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm mocking some data using Model Factories in Laravel. I need to use an external variable inside an Eloquent `each` method, but when I run the code I get an `Undefined variable` exception on that line.

Here`s my code:

```
$myVar = 45;

$collection = factory(MyClass::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($item) {
    // I need to use $myVar in here ...
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php   example #3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```html
$myVar = 45;

$collection = Factory(MyClass::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($item) use ($myVar){
            
       // Use it however you want
        });
```